# My Flash.SWF isn't playing

Tags: flash

I am very new at this.  I was asked to create a new site for this church.  They already had a flash.swf file running, I copied the page and did the modifications for he new inforamation, but the file won't play.  Here is the code,

```
#<OBJECT classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000"
 codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=6,0,0,0" id="flashslide" ALIGN="left" style="width: 501px; height: 254px">
 <PARAM NAME=movie VALUE="http://0068764.netsolhost.com/susann/flashslide.swf?src=flash-here.com&imglist_fn=getimglist.php&img_path=img&interval=5000&navbar=0&w=400&h=300" ref> 
  <PARAM NAME=quality VALUE=High> <PARAM NAME=scale VALUE=ExactFit> 
  <PARAM NAME=wmode VALUE=transparent> <PARAM NAME=bgcolor VALUE=#ffffff>
  <param name="_cx" value="11033">
  <param name="_cy" value="6403">
  <param name="FlashVars" value>
  <param name="Src" ref value="http://0068764.netsolhost.com/susann/flashslide.swf?src=flash-here.com&imglist_fn=getimglist.php&img_path=img&interval=5000&navbar=0&w=400&h=300">
  <param name="AllowScriptAccess" value>
  <param name="DeviceFont" value="0">
  <param name="EmbedMovie" value="0">
  <param name="SWRemote" value>
  <param name="MovieData" value>
  <param name="SeamlessTabbing" value="1">
  <param name="Profile" value="0">
  <param name="ProfileAddress" value>
  <param name="ProfilePort" value="0">
  <param name="AllowNetworking" value="all">
  <param name="AllowFullScreen" value="false">
 <EMBED src="http://0068764.netsolhost.com/susann/flashslide.swf?src=flash-here.com&amp;imglist_fn=getimglist.php&amp;img_path=img&amp;interval=5000&amp;navbar=0&amp;w=400&amp;h=300" quality=High scale=ExactFit wmode=transparent bgcolor=#ffffff NAME="flashslide" ALIGN=""
 TYPE="application/x-shockwave-flash" PLUGINSPAGE="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer" style="width: 501px; height: 254px"></EMBED></OBJECT></td>
```

#
oh another thing, why can't I see it play in Explorer?  The old site was only viewable in a foxfire browser.
Thank you!!!!

Comment: Can you please include all the html tags for the SWF insertion? I need to see the full object/embed tags

Comment: @Charlie: Post edited to have HTML as `code`

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that the swf exists? When I go to http://0068764.netsolhost.com/susann/flashslide.swf in a browser, I get a "page not found" error page.

That could be a simple explanation.